# How to disable lazy-loading for specific routes in Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, lazy-loading, vue-router, nuxt.js

It seems Nuxt has [pre-configured](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/905#issuecomment-311949978) to lazy load every route. How can I **disable** lazy-loading for some of my routes **so that they can be loaded along with the main bundle** as long as the website is visited?

In normal Vue CLI project, I can simply change:

```js
routes: [
  {
    path: '/some/link',
    component: () => import('./path/to/MyRouterView.vue')
  }
]
```

to

```js
import MyRouterView from './path/of/MyRouterView';

routes: [
  {
    path: '/some/link',
    component: MyRouterView
  }
]
```

But what's the equivalent approach for Nuxt project?

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://nuxtjs.org/api/components-nuxt-link/ way(adding `no-prefetch`) on `nuxt-link`

Comment: or you can use `resourceHints` (https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-render#resourcehints)

Comment: Sorry @hardik-shah but what I really mean by saying "disable lazy-loading" is to not code-split that route so it can be loaded along with main bundle instead of being a lazy one. I've revised my question.

Comment: oh... I will not recommend doing that! 
https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build#splitchunks or https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build#optimization should help you